# BibLatex: change maximum number of authors locally

Tags: biblatex

`biblatex` 1.6 "removed the local max/minnames and max/minitems options from \printbibliography and friends to enforce consistency. Please use the global options instead." (Release notes). However, when using several `printbibliography` e.g. to list the references corresponding to partners of a project and then references from the literature, it feels useful to be able to change the setting locally and have a more compact bibliography.

How can one bypass this limitation? Ideally I'd increment or modify a counter depending on the content of the `keywords` field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The per-`\printbibliography` option has been removed since the backend (Biber or BibTeX) needs to know the value for `(min/max)(bib/cite)names` in order to calculate things like `uniquelist`s correctly. If you change the value mid-document then the results of these derived features may come out weird.

The counters are still accessible on the `biblatex` side, so the naive approach would be to set them accordingly. As already mentioned that could yield undesirable results in edge cases when advanced features come into play.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\setmaxbibnames}{\numdef\blx@maxbibnames}
\newrobustcmd*{\setminbibnames}{\numdef\blx@minbibnames}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{four,
  author  = {One and Two and Three and Four},
  title   = {Four},
  date    = {2004},
}
@book{fouragain,
  author  = {One and Two and Three and Four},
  title   = {Four},
  date    = {2004},
  keywords = {again},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{four,fouragain}
\begingroup
\setmaxbibnames{999}
\printbibliography[keyword=again]
\endgroup
\printbibliography[notkeyword=again]
\end{document}
```

---

`(min/max)(bib/cite)names` can also be set on a per-entry basis, together with Biber's sourcemapping you can set them per keyword.

This approach has the huge advantage that all backend-created features like `uniquelist` will be aware of the settings and will act correctly, but it also means that the value is fixed for every entry.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
     \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{\bagain\b}, final]
     \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={,maxbibnames=999}, append]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{four,
  author  = {One and Two and Three and Four},
  title   = {Four},
  date    = {2004},
}
@book{fouragain,
  author  = {One and Two and Three and Four},
  title   = {Four},
  date    = {2004},
  keywords = {again},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{four,fouragain}
\printbibliography[keyword=again]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=again]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the question is general, I show how to change the `maxcitenames` locally in the document. (Based on @moewes answer above)

At some points of our document, we might want to explicitly mention all authors of a work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Here I set the maxcitenames as 2 for the document, unless the command \setmaxcitenames is used
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, natbib=true, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

%This commands overrides the above package option
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\setmaxcitenames}{\numdef\blx@maxcitenames}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{kottwitz2011latex,
author = {Kottwitz, Stefan},
publisher = {Packt Publishing},
title = {{LaTeX Beginner's Guide}},
url = {http://proquest.tech.safaribooksonline.de/9781847199867},
year = {2011}
}
@book{goossens1994latex,
author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander and Souidi, El Mamoun},
pages = {1120},
publisher = {Addison-Wesley Reading, Massachusetts},
title = {{The LATEX companion}},
url = {http://proquest.tech.safaribooksonline.de/0201362996},
volume = {2},
year = {1994}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
%Here is the preamble value maxnamecites 2
\citeauthor{kottwitz2011latex} has written a good book: \citetitle{kottwitz2011latex}, but \citeauthor{goossens1994latex} have written a classic, namely, \citetitle{goossens1994latex}.\\

%Now we change the maxnamecites to 10
\setmaxcitenames{10}
\citeauthor{kottwitz2011latex} has written a good book: \citetitle{kottwitz2011latex}, but \citeauthor{goossens1994latex} have written a classic, namely, \citetitle{goossens1994latex}.\\

%Finally, we set back to the default maxnamecites 2
\setmaxcitenames{2}
\citeauthor{kottwitz2011latex} has written a good book: \citetitle{kottwitz2011latex}, but \citeauthor{goossens1994latex} have written a classic, namely, \citetitle{goossens1994latex}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]