# New command like \textcite but with freely configurable number of authors

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, author-number

I am using biblatex and would like to define a new command like `\textcite` but with a freely configurable number of authors printed. In the rest of the document I still want to use the global configurations, e.g., the global `maxcitenames`.

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric-comp,bibstyle=numeric,backend=biber,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@BOOK{test1,
  AUTHOR    = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  TITLE     = {Test},
  YEAR      = {2000},
}  
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\newcommand{\textcitenew}[1]{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{#1}}\textcite}

\begin{document}
Reference to \textcite{test1} and \textcitenew{3}{test1}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The desired output is  `Reference to Author et al. [1] and Author, Buthor, Cuthor et al. [1].`

The actual output is `Reference to Author et al. [1] and Author et al. [1].`

[image: Reference to Author et al. 1 and Author et al. 1.]

I assume, a good solution would be to locally change `maxcitenames`, which unfortunately does not lead to the desired result in the example.

Clarification: I want the number of authors printed to be exactly equal to the argument of the new command (without truncation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- defined commands `\setmincitenames` and `\setmaxcitenames` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454871/123129) to the question [BibLatex: change maximum number of authors locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454868/123129))
- use parameter of `\textcitenew` to set mincitenames and maxcitenames locally

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric-comp,bibstyle=numeric,backend=biber,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@BOOK{test1,
  AUTHOR    = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  TITLE     = {Test},
  YEAR      = {2000},
}  
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\setmincitenames}{\numdef\blx@mincitenames}
\newrobustcmd*{\setmaxcitenames}{\numdef\blx@maxcitenames}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\textcitenew}[2]{{\setmincitenames{#1}\setmaxcitenames{#1}\textcite{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\textcite{test1}

2: \textcitenew{2}{test1}

3: \textcitenew{3}{test1}

4: \textcitenew{4}{test1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've added a clarification my question: I want the number of printed authors to be exactly equal to the argument of the new command `\textcitenew` without truncation. So this could be achieved by adding `\setminbibnames{#1}` to your command and by defining `\newrobustcmd*{\setminbibnames}{\numdef\blx@mincitenames}`. Please feel free to add this code to your answer, so that I can accept it (or post a better solution if there is one).

Comment: @chillibaba I edited the answer.